# I'm working on a C++ program where I'm facing a error during execution of if-else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to build a simple quiz program in C++  but I'm getting a runtime error. The source code of my quiz program is given below.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    char answer[100];
    int age,n=0;
    
    cout<<"Enter your name:- ";
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Welcome to this quiz game "<<name<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Enter your age :-";
    cin>>age;
    
    if(age<=10)
    {
        //Beginning of Question no.1
        cout<<"Who was the first president of India :- ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(answer,100); //User Inputs the answer here
        {   
            if(answer=="Rajendra Prasad" || answer=="rajendra Prasad" || answer=="rajendra prasad")
            {
                cout<<answer;
                cout<<"Your answer is right.";
                n=n+10;
                cout<<"You won "<<n<<" points :)";
            }
            else
            cout<<"Your answer is wrong.\nYou won 0 points but better luck next time.";
        //End of Question no.1
        }       
    }
}
```

But whenever user inputs the answer even though if the answer is right the execution directly jumps to else-statement instead of executing if-statement, so if anybody can help me solve this problem then I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: `char answer[100];` -> `std::string answer;`

Comment: Both `answer` and "Rajendra Prasad" are char*, `==` compares their address which will always be different. You should use `std::string` everywhere. (or `strcmp` if for some reason you really like char arrays)

Comment: The error has been solved, thank you very much : )